# Cannot start minecraft server on Ubuntu Snappy with docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, minecraft

I have a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Snappy on it.

I've installed minecraft server with

```
 docker pull itzg/minecraft-server
```

Following the instructions from https://hub.docker.com/r/itzg/minecraft-server/ I try to run

```
docker run -d -p 25565:25565 --name mc itzg/minecraft-server
```

or

```
   docker run -d -it -e EULA=TRUE -p 25565:25565 --name mc itzg/minecraft-server
```

However I get the following error:

```
$ docker run -d -it -e EULA=TRUE -p 25565:25565 --name mc itzg/minecraft-server
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "mc" is already in use by container a401d710b3c3. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

However, the `docker ps` reports no instance running

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

I did try to rename it to `mc2` as the error suggests, but the result is only more errors

Core question is, how do I properly make the minecraft-server run and resolve the error above ?

It is my first experience with docker, so please explain as clearly as possible.

**Additional info :**

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
08b7682eb487        itzg/minecraft-server:latest   "mc:latest"         38 minutes ago                                              cranky_rosalind     
d913adca07da        itzg/minecraft-server:latest   "mc"                39 minutes ago                                              furious_yonath      
e7fba87a02e4        itzg/minecraft-server:latest   "/start"            40 minutes ago                                              mc2                 
c3f3a1af49e3        itzg/minecraft-server:latest   "mc"                49 minutes ago                                              lonely_turing       
a401d710b3c3        itzg/minecraft-server:latest   "/start"            About an hour ago                                           mc                  
456bb2e52d8d        itzg/minecraft-server:latest   "/start"            About an hour ago                                           furious_bohr
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run a container, by default, it remains in your "history" (this is the "docker ps -a"). You can remove it either by doing "docker rm $containerid" or you can pass "--rm=true" during run to auto-remove it when it's shut down. The auto-remove is usually the recommended way for "temporary/one-time" containers.

Normally, if you do not provide a specific name, the system picks 2 random words and ends up auto generating a random name. However, in your case, you specified a name. This means that from that point on you need to do "docker start $name" and "docker stop $name". (alternatively you can use the $containerid instead of $name) Your other option is to stop and remove the container, and then you can re-launch it (re-create it).

Alternatively (not recommended), you can keep picking a new name each time and setting it -- in your case, mc3 will work. Then mc4, etc, but that doesn't make sense here...if you are going to do this, might as well leave out "--name"

So first run this to clean out all your past-ran containers:

> docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)

and

> docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)

Now, you have the following options (pick one - I suggest the first):

> docker run --rm=true -d -p 25565:25565 --name mc itzg/minecraft-server

Every time you shut down the container, it will blow away all settings/info/etc and next time you will start as though for the first time.

or

> docker run --rm=true -d -p 25565:25565 --name mc itzg/minecraft-server

and then followed each time by a:

> "docker stop mc" - to stop it
>   and
>   "docker start mc" - when you want to start it again

This will "preserve your settings", however, in your case you don't have a mounted volume, so there is nothing to really preserve. The end result will be roughly the same as in #1.